# Scrolling background transition creates ripple effect on Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, backbone.js

I'm currently working on a new site build, currently located at http://weve.wpengine.com/. As part of the site design, I've implemented a simple backbone.js view that scrolls the background at a different speed to the rest of the content to create a perspective illusion.

```
weve.ScrollTransitionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    templateId: 'template-page-background',
    className: 'page-background',   

    initialize: function () {
        var scope = this;

        var factor = 1.3;

        jQuery(window).scroll(function (e) {
            var scrollTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
            var position = 'top ' + (scrollTop / factor) + 'px center';
            scope.$el.css({ 'background-position': position });
        });
    }
});
```

This works fine in Firefox. However, in Chrome, there is a ripple effect upon scrolling - the background seems to only partially render in places and bits of the image get rendered out of place - and in I.E. the effect is jittery.

Initially I thought this may be an issue with the skewed elements on the page but after creating a mockup using partially transparent images rather than CSS skewed DOM elements I experienced the same problems.

Also, the mockup appeared to be fine when there were only a few elements on the page but when I translated this to the site where there were more text/images/elements on the page the rendering issue persisted.

I've found hints here and there in this and other forums for related rendering issues but nothing which seems to match the problem I'm experiencing.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue recently as well.  It's weird because it works fine for the first div with this effect, but with subsequent divs, the image comes up ripped, and some divs don't even show it.  I also see that it works fine in FF and Safari, but Chrome seems to have the issue (can't verify I.E.)

Comment: Hi Fishbowl, it took me a while but I eventually found a solution to this - I posted an answer below - hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution to this. The problem (for me) was related to the way that the Chrome rendering engine works (See: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/).

Essentially, the foreground of my page was divided into a series of sections that contained transformed (skewed) elements. Even though the sections themselves appeared as diagonals, the rendering engine treated them as squares with triangular transparent regions on opposing corners. When the background moved, these sections weren't being changed - which meant the rendering engine, in an effort to be faster and more efficient, wasn't re-rendering the transparent sections properly with the new background position, creating the jitter effect.

**The solution** was to add a line to my parallax javascript to subtly modify the css of each of the transformed sections each time the background changed. I set the script to adjust the background of the div element on each loop of the parallax code, alternating between two colours - rgba(255, 0, 255, 0) and rgba(255, 255, 0, 0) - which were different in theory but in practice 100% transparent. This forced the browser to re-render properly and solved the jitter problem.